# How to convert DateTime to String from query for using it in Google Visualization Chart?

Tags: coldfusion, google-visualization

I get the date data in this format `2018-04-01 00:00:00.0` in the query, and using the following code to add it as a string in the column:

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'StartDate');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Deficiency');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Withdraw');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Rain');
        data.addRows([
        <cfoutput query="display_data">
            [
            #dateTimeFormat(STARTPERIOD, "yyyy/dd/mm")#,
            #NumberFormat(DEF, '.9')#,                          
            #NumberFormat(WD,'.9')#,
            #NumberFormat(RAIN,'.9')#,
            ],
         </cfoutput>
            ]);
```

But I get an error in the console:

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Type mismatch. Value 504.5 does not match
>   type string in column index 0

Comment: Try putting `#dateTimeFormat(STARTPERIOD, "yyyy/dd/mm")#` in quotes. Like `"#dateTimeFormat(STARTPERIOD, "yyyy/dd/mm")#"`

Comment: That being said, I would rather create a ColdFusion array of array and then serialize in the JS code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try putting `#dateTimeFormat(STARTPERIOD, "yyyy/dd/mm")#` in quotes. Like `"#dateTimeFormat(STARTPERIOD, "yyyy/dd/mm")#"`.

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'StartDate');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Deficiency');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Withdraw');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Rain');
    data.addRows([
    <cfoutput query="display_data">
        [
        '#dateTimeFormat(STARTPERIOD, "yyyy/dd/mm")#',
        #NumberFormat(DEF, '.9')#,                          
        #NumberFormat(WD,'.9')#,
        #NumberFormat(RAIN,'.9')#,
        ],
     </cfoutput>
]);
```

The way I would do this is the following.

```
<cfset dataArray = []>
<cfloop query="display_data">
  <cfset ArrayAppend(dataArray, [dateTimeFormat(display_data.STARTPERIOD, "yyyy/dd/mm"), NumberFormat(display_data.DEF, '.9'), NumberFormat(display_data.WD,'.9'), NumberFormat(display_data.RAIN,'.9')])>
</cfloop>
<script>
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'StartDate');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Deficiency');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Withdraw');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Rain');
    data.addRows(<cfoutput>#serializeJSON(dataArray)#</cfoutput>);
</script>
```

For ColdFusion 2016 and above you can use the following.

```
<cfscript>
  dataArray = [];
  display_data.each(function(value, index){
    dataArray.append([dateTimeFormat(value.STARTPERIOD, "yyyy/dd/mm"), NumberFormat(value.DEF, '.9'), NumberFormat(value.WD,'.9'), NumberFormat(value.RAIN,'.9')]);
  });
</cfscript>
```